# specific redirect required using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to do a very specific url redirect using mod_rewrite within an .htaccess. Below is a url which has to map to the url below it:

m.example.com/123456/123456-product-name/

This needs to map to the following:

m.example.com/product-name/123456

I'm still getting to grips with regex and url rewrites and I've spent a good couple of hours trying to get this right. Can anybody help!?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that. in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^\d+/(\d+)-([^/]+) /$2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or just [L] (and not [R=301,L]), if you do that without redirection.